# MVC 3 Changing Home route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, controller

It's my first MVC project and my customer doesn't want any links like xxx.com/Home/Index or something like that. When i change my controller name the browser looking for /Home and it gives me an ex. Bec there's no HomeController.

How can i change it the default controller "Home" with another one.

Answer (score 4):

Just change your ***Default route***:

**Default route created in Global.asax** *(Unchanged)*

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Modify the defaults for the parameters (`controller`, `action`, etc.).  Something like this:

**Modified Default route** *(Changed)*

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "YourNewController", action = "SomeOtherAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: even I am having the same issue, I changed like in routes.Maproute() but now it is neither going Home nor a Specific Controller.

Answer (score 1):

The routes are set in the `Global.asax` file in the `RegisterRoutes(RoteCollection routes)` routine.  The default route is specified as:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

You would need to change the `"Home"` part to your new controller name.

You can also set up additional routes as required (see [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)).